# Given A,B such that rank $A_{m \times n} = m \Rightarrow \exists C: AC = B$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A,B be matrices $m \times n$ and rank A $ = m$.

How to prove that there exists matrix C such that AC = B?

Comment: If you think in the mappings described by matrices, what does $\operatorname{rank} A = m$ mean?

Comment: linearly independent rows

Comment: That's not in terms of the mapping $x \mapsto Ax$. Think of that mapping.

Comment: Got it. For any b there is x such that solves system Ax. Hence, treating B as a set of columns, we know that such C does exist. Thanks!